# Bluetooth UUID iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I have a problem connecting to a bluetooth LE device. I managed to get a centralmanager working and I can detect bluetooth LE devices, however, I now want to be able to link my local storage of items to the found bluetooth devices when able, but there's no way to link the two for several reasons:

1. The peripherals I find, give me an identifier (I don't know what I can do with this and where its origin is from)
2. I cannot access raw advertising data.

In my local database I do have access to the bluetooth MAC address from the devices. Is there a way to create a UUID that equals the one I find in the peripherals identifier?

I have tried to create a NSUUID from string, but failed. I aslo tried to create a CBUUID from string, but that too failed.

MAC address is in `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` format, where it can be numbers as well as characters and the peripheral identifier has the format `AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDDDDDDDDD` where it can be numbers as well as characters. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here is a link to a working sample app I put together for interfacing to a Heart Rate monitor.  It may help to understand how to communicate with the devices. https://github.com/tedrog36/HealthKitApp-Swift

Comment: Core Bluetooth does not provide the MAC address. The identifier that is provided when a peripheral is discovered can be stored and used to connect to the peripheral in the future (You can get a CBPeripheral instance using `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` And/or perform a discovery scan again and compare the identifier against your target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fixed it by advertising unique data by the peripheral, data I already possess in the database. I can link this data to a list item. I do this in the `didDiscover` function.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let uniqueID = (advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"] as! NSArray).firstObject!
}
```

Comment: hello, i have the same problem as you, i just got uuid of bluetooth, is there any way to get bluetooh address

Comment: No, there is not. I have done further research with several developers, and the bluetooth address and the bluetooth MAC address change every now and then (not sure when, how and why, but they're not the same throughout the connections).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
Do you know there is something about bluetooth that doesn't change, but on both devices see it together?

Comment: As far as I know, nope. But there is of course your advertisement data. I highly recommend using that!

Answer (score 2):

When you find any peripheral in blue-tooth  ,you will get details in below delegate method

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    <CBPeripheral: 0x18092fa0, identifier = 123JKDSF-F0E3-F96A-F0A3-64A68508A53C, name = PERIPHERAL_NAME, state = disconnected>
     advertisementData 
    {
      kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 0;
      kCBAdvDataLocalName = PERIPHERAL_NAME;
      }
}
```

Here **identifier** Apple will generate it based on some calculations, and it should be changes every time for same Peripheral device whenever **central** will found it.
For MAC address Some device will provide MAC address but not sure you will get every time like **Android**.
We have one option to get **MAC** address, first we need to connect peripheral device to **central(Mobile)**.
After connection happen check below methods you will get **MAC** address of Bluetooth device in **iOS**

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error;
{
for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
        {
            [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
 }

- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{        uint8_t val[characteristic.value.length];
        [characteristic.value getBytes:val length:characteristic.value.length];
        if ([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:BT_SIG_DEVICE_INFO_SYSTEM_ID])
        {
          NSString * strDeviceID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx",val[7],val[6],val[5],val[2],val[1],val[0]];
        NSLog(@"strDeviceID.ServerID= %@",[strDeviceID uppercaseString]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do however work in swift, but I can see and unserstand what you did here. However, before I can connect to the device, I need to make sure it is my device, so for now, this is not enough...

Comment: You can identify based in **peripheral name** in  below method
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI

Comment: The name I get is not the one I'm looking for (I only get the correct name after connecting to the device) => Cheers Apple

Comment: At this line: NSString * strDeviceID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx",val[7],val[6],val[5],val[2],val[1],val[0]];

What's the reason of the value's orders?

Comment: @AlfredoLucoG - This is the value of IEEE (MAC address of Bluetooth device). Here we can get major and minor , So we can filter by above format to get mac address.

Comment: @Haric I don't understand how to use it, do you have a Swift form?